# LINQ Query - Selecting a key based upon the value having a property that matches a string?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreach, key-value

I have an IDictionary

I need to select the first Foo where the Bar.Prop1 matches a string value.

```
public class Foo { }

public class Bar
{
    public String Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

right now I have it like so...

```
foreach (var kvp in MyDictionary)
{
    if (kvp.Value.Prop1 == theString)
    {
        var key = kvp.Key;
        //Do something with it
        break;
    }
}
```

But that just doesn't seem as clean as a LINQ Query is. ReSharper turned it into:

```
foreach (var kvp in MyDictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Prop1 == theString))
{
    var key = kvp.Key;
    //Do something with it
    //break; is unnecessary because I only get one kvp back anyways.
}
```

I only want the very first item that matches, because I don't ever expect to get back more than one KVP. That goes against the business logic, so Unit Testing takes care of that.

Comment: It does seem like you're using the dictionary backwards, using a value to find a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I only want the very first item that
>   matches, because I don't ever expect
>   to get back more than one KVP. That
>   goes against the business logic, so
>   Unit Testing takes care of that.

If this is the case, I would argue you need to use a stronger code guarantee of your intention, and that would be the `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`) method. `First` is going to return the first object *of arbitrarily many* that match a given predicate. If *many* goes against your expectations and business rules, this seems to be an error. Treat it as such.

```
var key = MyDictionary.Single(pair => pair.Value.Prop1 == someValue).Key;
```

With `Single`, if there is more than one matching item in a sequence, it will result in an exception.

`SingleOrDefault` allows for 0 or 1, but never more. If using this approach, you'd want to capture the result and compare to null before performing additional operations with it (firing methods, accessing properties, etc.).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. For me, SingleOrDefault because I can have 0 or 1 values that match my predicate.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `IDictionary` doesn't guarantee the order of results, and `Dictionary<K,V>` uses a hash table internally, so `First` is even less useful here. +1.

Answer (score 5):

```
var key = MyDictionary.First(kvp => kvp.Value.Prop1 == theString).Key;
```

Answer (score 4):

@Bala R's answer is correct, but Anthony Pegram makes a very good point in his comment on the OP. If you're doing this more than a few times with different keys, what you should do instead is reverse the dictionary, so you don't have to traverse the entire collection every time you want a value.

```
// Do this just once: it's expensive
var reverseDict = MyDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value.Prop1, kvp => kvp.Key);

...
// Do this as many times as you need: it's cheap
var key = reverseDict[someValue];
```